# Android ndk-build iostream: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, iostream

I'm having a problem with compiling a *.cpp* file using the ndk-build tool (Windows 7 with Cygwin).

The error appears when I try to compile the *.cpp* file with #include:

```
jni/native.cpp:5:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
```

Here is my *.cpp* file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_SampleActivity"
#define  LOG_TAG    "hellojni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void Java_com_test_ndk_SampleActivity_helloLog(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisobj, jstring logThis)
{
    jboolean isCopy;

    const char * szLogThis = env->GetStringUTFChars(logThis, &isCopy);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", szLogThis);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(logThis, szLogThis);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And here is my *Android.mk* file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

APP_STL:=stlport_static

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := swingbyte-android

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include-all
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have iostream file in the Android NDK folder (*NDK_ROOT\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include*), but I don't have any idea how to tell compiler to look for iostream (and other standard header files) in that folder.

It seems to that I'm missing one or few environment variables, or some compiler flags.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think "APP_STL:=stlport_static" must be in Application.mk file.

Create a "Application.mk" file and write "APP_STL:=stlport_static" in it.

Comment: I got this line in Android.mk, you can see that in my post.

Comment: You should put that line in APPLICATION.mk file, not ANDROID.mk

Comment: Yep! APPLICATION.mk has a different role than ANDROID.mk, and it must be created at jni's root (-> projet_dir/jni/Application.mk). (thanks Martins)

Comment: You may run into shared_ptr error, so in that case use: APP_STL := gnustl_static

Comment: What to do when you use Gradle 2.10 / experimental:0.6.0-alpha7 ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES +=  libstlport

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/stlport/stlport 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += bionic
```

Comment: What is `bionic` for??

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
```

Or whatever revision you use solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android NDK to the latest one.

I faced the error in Android NDK version 5.

Comment: I am using ndk in Android Studio 2.1.1.  Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent days to update my NDK from r10e to r20, and there're several variables that are changed.

**For NDK r10e**

File *Android.mk*:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./main.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -frtti
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -D__cplusplus=201103L
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

File *Application.mk*:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

**For NDK r20**

File *Android.mk*:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./main.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -frtti
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -D__cplusplus=201103L -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

File *Application.mk*:

```
APP_ABI := all
# In general, you can only use a static variant of the C++ runtime if you have one and only one shared library in your application.
APP_STL := c++_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

And my *main.cpp* file (including my *bin_node.h* file):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("****************** tree node ******************\n");
    amo::BinNode<int> root(0);
    amo::BinNode<int>* lchild1 = root.insertLeftChild(1);
    amo::BinNode<int>* rchild2 = root.insertRightChild(2);
    amo::BinNode<int>* lchild3 = lchild1->insertLeftChild(3);
    amo::BinNode<int>* rchild4 = lchild1->insertRightChild(4);
    amo::BinNode<int>* lchild5 = rchild2->insertLeftChild(5);
    amo::BinNode<int>* rchild6 = rchild2->insertRightChild(6);
    amo::BinNode<int>* lchild7 = lchild3->insertLeftChild(7);
    amo::BinNode<int>* rchild8 = lchild3->insertRightChild(8);
    amo::BinNode<int>* lchild9 = rchild6->insertLeftChild(9);
    amo::BinNode<int>* rchild10 = rchild6->insertRightChild(10);
    amo::BinNode<int>* lchild11 = rchild8->insertLeftChild(11);
    amo::BinNode<int>* rchild12 = rchild8->insertRightChild(12);

    printf("going to root.traversePre()\n");
    root.traversePre();

    printf("going to root.traversePreLoop()\n");
    root.traversePreLoop();

    printf("going to root.traversePreLoop2()\n");
    root.traversePreLoop2();

    printf("\n****************** main return ******************\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Run ndk-build and build an executable file**

[image]

For more source code and information for this, check [my GitHub](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/NDK).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57053600/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.