# Cmake Opencv for Android under Windows... can't find iostream

Tags: android, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to run the cmake_android.cmd script for opencv as detailed here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0#Windows_.28native.29

So I can get an OpenCV.mk file to use with Android

So I start cmd.exe
When I am in `opencv\android`
I run `scripts\cmake_android.cmd`

It gets to about 3% and fails because it can't find iostream

```
[  3%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o
C:\opencv\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_stream.cxx:31:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
```

This is my wincfg.cmd file

```
:: variables required for OpenCV build ::
:: Note: all pathes should be specified without tailing slashes!
SET ANDROID_NDK=C:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b
SET CMAKE_EXE=C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe
SET MAKE_EXE=%ANDROID_NDK%\prebuilt\windows\bin\make.exe

:: variables required for android-opencv build ::
SET ANDROID_SDK=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
SET ANT_DIR=C:\opencv\android\apache-ant-1.8.4
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09

:: configuration options ::
:::: general ARM-V7 settings
SET ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
SET BUILD_DIR=build

:::: uncomment following lines to compile for old emulator or old device
::SET ANDROID_ABI=armeabi
::SET BUILD_DIR=build_armeabi

:::: uncomment following lines to compile for ARM-V7 with NEON support
::SET ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a with NEON
::SET BUILD_DIR=build_neon

:::: uncomment following lines to compile for x86
::SET ANDROID_ABI=x86
::SET BUILD_DIR=build_x86

:::: other options
::SET ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=8   &:: android-3 is enough for native part of OpenCV but android-8 is required for Java API
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130429/android-ndk-build-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to compile project code using NDK.  I am trying to build OpenCV using cmake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NDK r8b you need the latest OpenCV from repository.

OpenCV 2.4.2 release supports NDKs from r5 to r8. And the prebuild Android binaries from sourceforge and Google Play were compiled with NDK r8.

Comment: Thanks!  I learned this I think about the same time you answered it.  I successfully compiled everything.  My project is now working on my phone.  Awesome!