# Application.mk is ignored by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I would like to include c++ header iostream into my NDK code. In order to do that, I have to include APP_STL := stlport_static (or similar) into Application.mk file as mentioned in [Android ndk-build iostream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130429/android-ndk-build-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory).

It all works well if I compile using command line ndk-build, however while compiling using Android Studio, I still get the same error as iostream not found. It looks like application.mk is ignored by Android Studio and I am not sure how to configure it in build.gradle.
Can anyone help me including APP_STL := stlport_static using android studio?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `stl "stlport_static"` to the `ndk` section of your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Androidme Don't forget to mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like at the moment there is no support for including Application.mk file in build.gradle, however adding stl "stlport_static" under ndk section of build.gradle works well (thanks Michael for quick reply).

Under defaultConfig section, add:

```
    ndk {
        moduleName "app"
        stl "stlport_static"
    }
```

Details can be found at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/pHnST37HrlM

Comment: You can include Application.mk and compile only one command line and include jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call in your build.gradle to ignore automatic build by Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

For Gradle 2.5, it should look like this:

```
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "app"
        stl = "stlport_static"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle 4.4 :
Adding

```
path 'jni/Application.mk'
```

to the app level build.gradle solved my problem. It should be like this

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'jni/Android.mk'
        path 'jni/Application.mk'
    }
}
```

Then Android Studio checks for your Application.mk file.

[My folder structure is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beYWX.png)